# HTML FORM - setting form action on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http

i've been having a problem where i have a form in which several entities within an unordered list are displayed, a name and a button dinamically with vanilla javascript. The problem is, im changing the action value from the html form, from javascript this so i can add an id that i get in a JSON from a http request so i can manipulate a specific object, but it doesnt send the "delete" request, which is actually a post request that im managing from my server side correctly (tested in postman and works like a charm), but when calling from the front-end it stops working. Here are my html and script.

**PANEL.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https://cdn.example.net; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/panel-style.css">
    <script defer src="panel-script.js"></script>
    <title>Panel de Control</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img src="assets/mrvapeslogo.png" alt="mrvapes logo">
        <a href="index.html"></a>
    </header>
    <section>
        <form id="files-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" autocomplete="off" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
            <label for="user">Banners Activos</label><br/>
            <ul id="files-container">

            </ul>
        </form>
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:3000/banner" autocomplete="off" method="POST" target="_blank">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="button-wrap">
                    <!-- <label class="button" for="upload">Subir</label> -->
                    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nombre de Archivo" value="" name="name" required>
                    <input id="image" name="file" value="Subir" placeholder="Subir Archivo" type="file" required>
                    <button id="upload" value="post-request" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                    <!-- <input id="upload" type=" submit " value="Enviar " onclick="submit() "> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
```

**PANEL-SCRIPT.JS**

```
const list = document.getElementById("files-container");
const filesForm = document.getElementById("files-form");

fetch('http://localhost:3000/banner')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
        console.log(json.message)
        for (let i = 0; i < json.message.length; i++) {
            var item = `<li>${json.message[i].name}
                            <button id="delete-button" onclick="deleteButton('${json.message[i].name}','${json.message[i]._id}')">Borrar</button>
                        </li>`;
            list.innerHTML += item;
        }
    });

function deleteButton(name, id) {
    var answer = confirm(`Seguro que deseas borrar ${name}?`);
    if (answer) {
        filesForm.action = `http://localhost:3000/banner/${id}`;
        alert('Borrado Correctamente!');
        window.location.reload(true);
    } else {
        validate();
    }
}

function validate() {
    return false
}
```

HAPPY HOLIDAYS! :D

**-- UPDATE --**

When making these changes below to my panel-script.js, my delete function starts working but everytime i cancel the confirm dialog it forwards me to a "cannot post page".

```
function deleteButton(name, id) {
    var answer = confirm(`Seguro que deseas borrar ${name}?`);
    if (answer) {
        filesForm.action = `http://localhost:3000/banner/${id}`;
        alert('Borrado Correctamente!');
        // window.location.reload(true);
    } else {
        // validate();
        return false;
    }
}

// function validate() {
//     return false
// }
```

Comment: The form submit process starts navigation to the action url but then you also are trying to call window.reload() which is not compatible with the form navigation

Comment: already deleted the "window.location.reload(true);" but it didnt work